# React Native setting state of another Component

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native

I need to update the state of BackGround.js from HomeScreen.js. Currently I take in JSON of the format:

```
{
"navigate": "background",
"media": "red",
"sound_bool": "false",
"sound": ""
}
```

as an argument over socket. From there I use the navigate parameter to determine which component to navigate to. I would like to send the media parameter from the JSON to the component that is being navigated to, in order to change state. How should I go about doing this?

HomeScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Image, Text, StyleSheet, Button, View, Dimensions, Vibration} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'

console.ignoredYellowBox = [
    'Setting a timer'
]


const io = require('socket.io-client');
let server = 'http://redacted:3000';
let socket = io(server, {
  transports: ['websocket']
});


export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      backgroundColor: 'orange',
    }; 


  }
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }
  render(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    socket.on('json emission', json => {
      var json_dump = JSON.parse(json);
      var navi = json_dump.navigate;
      var media = json_dump.media;
      //parse JSON and send commands from here
      switch(navi){
      case 'image':
        navigate('IS');
        break;
      case 'background':
        navigate('BG');
        break;
      case 'buttons':
        navigate('BB');
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Error invalid navigation command: " + navi);
        break;
      }
    });
      return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor, flex: 1}}>

      </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

BackGround.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Image, Text, StyleSheet, Button, View, Dimensions, Vibration} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'

export default class BackGround extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    }; 
  }
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
 }
 render(){
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
 return (
 <View style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor, flex: 1}}>
 </View>
 );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/), which I assume you are, you can pass a prop to the navigation target by passing an object as the second parameter in your `navigate()` call.  For example:

```
case 'image':
    this.props.naviagtion.navigate('IS',{ media: media });
    break;
```

The media property will then be available in the target component in the `this.props.navigation.state.params.media` property.

This code has not been tested, but it should work.

Comment: Glad I could help.